# Corrupt PDF generated after LaTex build

Tags: pdf, compiling

So I have sometimes (and this is important) the issue that either a completely blank PDF which I can view OR a partially blank PDF with only the \maketitle and \tableofcontents is visible OR a completely corrupt PDF which I cannot view is generated after I build the document. VS Code says that the file built without an error. I use the LaTex Workshop Extension for VS Code and haven't changed there a thing. I'm on Windows 10, latest update. MikTex is also up-to-date and in the System variables included. It worked before without those corruptions happening often but now it got to a point where it really annoys me.

The error message in the console I get when I open the .PDF file through the 'View in web browser' button with the LaTex Workshop Extension in the Firefox Webbrowser is:

> Uncaught (in promise)  Object { message: "Invalid PDF structure.",
> name: "InvalidPDFException", stack:
> "BaseExceptionClosure@http://127.0.0.1:53682/build/pdf.js:1296:29\n__webpack_modules__<@http://127.0.0.1:53682/build/pdf.js:1299:2\n__w_pdfjs_require__@http://127.0.0.1:53682/build/pdf.js:15089:41\n__webpack_modules__<@http://127.0.0.1:53682/build/pdf.js:302:32\n__w_pdfjs_require__@http://127.0.0.1:53682/build/pdf.js:15089:41\n__webpack_modules__<@http://127.0.0.1:53682/build/pdf.js:237:41\n__w_pdfjs_require__@http://127.0.0.1:53682/build/pdf.js:15089:41\n@http://127.0.0.1:53682/build/pdf.js:15099:18\n@http://127.0.0.1:53682/build/pdf.js:15100:12\nwebpackUniversalModuleDefinition@http://127.0.0.1:53682/build/pdf.js:31:50\n@http://127.0.0.1:53682/build/pdf.js:32:3\n"
> }

Opening the PDF in Adobe Acrobat gives:

> There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and
> could not be repaired.

Opening the PDF in SumatraPDF gives:

> Error while opening PATH_TO_PDF_FILE

The .tex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks]{scrartcl}
\author{My Name}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for things like align
\usepackage[english]{babel} % document language
\usepackage{lmodern} % for modern fonts with sections
\usepackage{graphicx} %for graphics
\usepackage{csquotes} %for quotes
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % for KOMA-conform headings
\usepackage{esvect} % for better vector notaion
\usepackage{siunitx} % for SI Units
\usepackage{enumitem} % to use custom enumerated lists
\usepackage{xparse} % for the NewDocumentCommand command
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref} %for better hyperreferencing in PDF documents

\begin{document}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\today}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\ifoot{mat}
\ofoot{My School}
\ihead{\copyright \, My Name}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}Page\nobreakspace\thepage}}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\newlist{exmpl}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exmpl]{
  leftmargin=*,
  label={Example \arabic*)}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\example}{ m }{%
    \item #1
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\solution}{ m }{%
    \emph{Solution:}%
    #1
}

% \begin{exmpl}
%     \example{A tractor pulls a felled tree along the ground for a distance of 200 m. 
%         If the tractor exerts a force of 500 N, how much work will be done?\\}
%     \solution{
%         Work done $=$ force $*$ distance moved in direction of force.
%         \[\text{Work done}=5000 N \cdot 200 m =1MJ\]}
% \end{exmpl}

\title{2nd year mathematics resume}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\pagebreak

% \include{chapters/trigonometry.tex}
% \include{chapters/trigonometric_functions.tex}
% \include{chapters/vectors.tex}
% \include{chapters/arithmetic_sequences_and_series.tex}
% \include{chapters/transformations_of_graphs.tex}

\end{document}
```

The .log file gives this: https://send.vis.ee/download/b83a0aaf0e30364d/#9wKDcaCHnC_i-2_B0t51uQ The file expires after 7 days and / or after 20 downloads.

Comment: your question is archived here forever please don't use a link which will time out. Please make a complete small file that shows the problem and add the log here.  Your curret example has no sections so `\tableofcontents` can not do much.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It works again. The PDF isn't corrupt anymore after I've added some text to the main .tex file and re-compiled it. What do you mean by a complete small file? 

And the problem is, the problem doesn't happen regularly. Sometimes after compiling the PDF a second time, without any change it corrupts and sometimes it wont.

Comment: well the example you posted is complete but I suspected it isn't an example of the problem since it had no sections so table for contents is empty. But if your example is working then it isn't clear what answer anyone can give here?

Comment: the document posted runs without error in an up to date texlive 2021

Comment: Well I loaded in the sections separately with \include. It didn't work before but now it does. It is really strange why it happens. I expected I expected an answer to why sometimes the PDF can corrupt during the build process. The document also doesn't give me any error during build process but sometimes the PDF won't show correctly. It is either completely blank or straight up corrupt.

Comment: reasons are usually that you (or something) killed the job before pdftex finished writing the file or that you included a pdf image made elsewhere with an error. I have never seen pdftex write a corrupr pdf file on its own.

Comment: Well I let it compile without interrupting it as far as I know. Maybe it is because of Synology Drive which syncs that busy PDF automatically to my NAS and thus corrupts the file? That could indeed be the case. Anyways thanks for trying to help!